# Why UILabel increasing memory usage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-management, ios7

So, i have some boundaries (*`addBoundaryWithIdentifier:`*), a have code which generate blocks (*`UIView`* squares) every second with *`performSelector:`*, the blocks fall and if collision with boundary happened i remove item.

Now, if i add UILabel to view, memory usage slowly increase up to 15Mb and then stop climbing.

**Memory using without UILabel:**
[image]
**Memory using with UILabel:**
[image]
**Memory using with UILabel after couple minutes:**
[image]

What's going on here? How to fix that? Should i fix that?

This is the code I'm using.

```
@implementation ESViewController {
    UIPushBehavior *pushBlock;
    UIDynamicAnimator *mainAnimator;
    UICollisionBehavior *blockCollision;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

//    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(110, 400, 100, 50)];
//    [label setText:@"Hello"];
//    [label setTextAlignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];
//    [self.view addSubview: label];

    mainAnimator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView: self.view];

    blockCollision = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems: @[]];
    [blockCollision addBoundaryWithIdentifier:@"bottom"
                                    fromPoint:CGPointMake(0, 480)
                                      toPoint:CGPointMake(320, 480)];
    [blockCollision addBoundaryWithIdentifier:@"left"
                                    fromPoint:CGPointMake(0, 480)
                                      toPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [blockCollision addBoundaryWithIdentifier:@"right"
                                    fromPoint:CGPointMake(320, 480)
                                      toPoint:CGPointMake(320, 0)];
    [blockCollision addBoundaryWithIdentifier:@"top"
                                    fromPoint:CGPointMake(0, -40)
                                      toPoint:CGPointMake(320, -40)];
    [blockCollision setCollisionDelegate: (id<UICollisionBehaviorDelegate>)self];
    [mainAnimator addBehavior: blockCollision];

    pushBlock = [[UIPushBehavior alloc] initWithItems: @[] mode: UIPushBehaviorModeContinuous];
    [pushBlock setAngle: M_PI/2 magnitude:0.05];
    [mainAnimator addBehavior: pushBlock];

    [self movingBlocks];
}

- (void) movingBlocks {
    UIView *block = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(arc4random() % 320, -20, 20, 20)];
    [block setBackgroundColor: [UIColor brownColor]];
    [self.view addSubview: block];
    [blockCollision addItem: block];
    [pushBlock addItem: block];
    [self performSelector:@selector(movingBlocks) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.05];
}

- (void)collisionBehavior:(UICollisionBehavior *)behavior
      beganContactForItem:(id<UIDynamicItem>)item
   withBoundaryIdentifier:(id<NSCopying>)identifier
                  atPoint:(CGPoint)p {
    [pushBlock removeItem:item];
    [blockCollision removeItem:item];
    [(UIView*)item removeFromSuperview];
}

@end
```

Comment: Does Instruments show a leak? If not then there's no grounds to conclude that anything needs fixing. 15mb of RAM completely unused is no less beneficial than 15mb being used as a cache but would be instantly released if there were a low memory warning, so UIKit will often prefer the latter.

Comment: [Please include the relevant code **in** your question, and not on a third party site that can go offline without notice.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code)

Comment: Your code isn't (based on the above) using any UILabels.

Comment: @HotLicks Look at the top; it's commented out. It's literally one UILabel.

Comment: @RobNapier - Like I said, the above code isn't using any UILabels.

Comment: Stupid question:  How often do you create a new ESViewController?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem is in the tool being used rather than the asker's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reproduced the symptom you're describing, but I believe Xcode is lying to you and you should open a radar (bugreport.apple.com).

If you run this in Instruments, memory usage is exactly as you would expect. I've tried having Xcode profile in Release mode (like Instruments does), and I've run on all the iPad simulators. The symptom is very reproducible in Xcode, while Instruments shows expected results and is very stable. I even transferred a running process that was showing growth in Xcode over to Instruments, and Instruments still shows no growth. I'd say Xcode is busted here.